# Facebook, twitter and mail share without UIActivityViewController on iOS

Tags: ios

I want my app users to be able to share stuff on facebook, twitter and mail but I do not want to show the UIActivityViewController..
So I want to have seperate buttons for different share types (fb, twitter, mail) instead of just one share button, and show directly the share dialog.
Is there a way of doing this?

Thank you..

Comment: Please, clear your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there are different way to do it.there is build in framework for it...

```
SLComposeViewController /// for facebook and twitter
```

and

```
MFMailComposeViewController /// for Email
```

check this link [here](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2012/07/tutorial-how-to-use-inbuilt.html) for facebook and twitter

and for sharing with Email check [here](http://www.codingexplorer.com/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-send-email-in-your-apps/)